# Custom bluetooth protocol support in Android

Tags: android, bluetooth

With the basic BT libraries available with Android OS, is creating a custom protocol to interface with a proprietary BT device supported?  I've worked a bit with the TCP/IP stack, and it was *fairly* straightforward, but before I try to support BT I'd like to know how difficult that would be.  I could see BT protocols being locked down to a few well known ones.

I did a bit of Googling on this and either my search text kung fu is not up to par, or documentation for doing this is quite sparse.

So, in summation, does Android OS (2.3+) support building your own protocols, and if so, where can I find documentation on it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if you'd like to build on a rfcomm stack, insecure connections are available at API level 10. [Bluetooth Dev Article](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/wireless/bluetooth.html). For other protocols like l2cap or ACL there is no API for that.

Comment: hmm... it looks like I'm going to need to step back a layer and work on defining a BT service.